# What does time_t mean?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

According to http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/time_t/ time_t is the number of seconds since midnight 1/1/1970 UTC. So if I call the time function as documented here http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/time/ does the number of seconds returned go from the epoch until now in UTC or to the time as adjusted by the standard timezone for the host it's running on?

And, more importantly, why is this not documented?

Comment: You will save a lot of effort by storing all times as UTC. Convert to local time only when you want to display it.

Comment: Ran the following program under windows:

// timetest.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
 time_t now;
 time(&now);
 printf("Seconds since epoch %ld", now);
 return now;
}

and it returned a time with my timezone set as Eastern. I then closed Visual C++, changed my timezone to Pacific, restarted C++ and re-ran the program which returned 50 more seconds than before, approximately how long it too me to run the program.

So the VC++ libraries under windows appear to return UTC.

Comment: Of course, Loki. What led you to believe I wasn't doing that?

Comment: @Thom: Looks documented to me http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1f4c8f33(v=VS.100).aspx.  www.cplusplus.com leaves a lot of info out, and some of it is just plain wrong.  (Especially now that C++11 is out)

Comment: Just to clarify: neither the C nor C++ standards define the resolution or epoch, but POSIX does.

Comment: That thunking sound is me pounding my head against my desk. Thanks for the help, guys. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

UTC . localtime() and buddies map to
local timezone.

Comment: See my note about time() above under windows.

Answer (score 2):

`time_t` is implementation defined according to the standard, in VC++ it's simply a `typedef` for `__int64`. The value is returned from `time()`: the implementation’s best approximation to the current calendar time. The value (time_t)(-1) is returned if the calendar time is not
available.

Answer (score 1):

It contains the time since the epoch, adjusted for the local timezone

```
time_t time(time_t *tloc) -- returns the time since 00:00:00 GMT, Jan. 1, 1970, measured in seconds.
```

**[invalid]**

*The structure contains the time since the epoch in seconds, up to 1000 milliseconds of more precise interval, the local time zone (measured in minutes of time westward from Greenwich), and a flag that, if nonzero, indicates that Day light Saving time applies locally during the appropriate part of the year.*

**[/invalid]**

Comment: I don't know about your machine @KevinDTimm, but on mine it's a typedef for `__int64`.

Comment: Crap, sorry about that, my answer contains information from two different functions, fixes being inserted .......

Comment: you are confusing it with `struct tm`